# angular-bootstrap - repeatedly calling $compile with bootstrap tooltip causes slowness

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an app set up using polling once a second to update a pie chart directive.  I'm using d3 to draw the pie chart, and I wanted to use bootstrap tooltips on the pie chart.  To achieve this I'm using angular-bootstrap, and manually calling $compile every time the data updates to process the tooltip directive.  It looks like this:

```
app.directive('piechart', ['$compile', function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: { data: '=', w: '=width', h: '=height', label: '=' },
      link: function(scope, element) {

        ...

        var svg = d3.select(element[0])
              .append('svg')
                .attr('width', scope.w)
                .attr('height', scope.h);

        scope.$watch('data', function(newValue) {

          if (newValue) {

            var pieData = pie(newValue);

            var arcs = svg.selectAll('g.arc')
              .data(pieData, function(d) { return d.data.label; });

            arcs.attr('tooltip', function(d, i) { 
                  return scope.data[i].label + ': ' + scope.data[i].value; 
                }).select('path')
                .transition()
                .delay(100)
                .duration(750)
                .attrTween('d', arcTween);

            var enteredArcs = arcs.enter()
              .append('g')
                .attr('class', 'arc')
                .attr('transform', 'translate(' + outerRadius + ',' + outerRadius + ')')
                .attr('tooltip-append-to-body', true)
                .attr('tooltip', function(d, i) { 
                  return scope.data[i].label + ': ' + scope.data[i].value; 
                });

            enteredArcs.append('path')
                .attr('fill', 'white')
                .attr('stroke', 'white')
                .attr('stroke-width', 2)
                .on('mouseover', function() { d3.select(this).transition().duration(500).attr('d', arcOver); }) 
                .on('mouseout', function() { d3.select(this).transition().duration(200).attr('d', arc); })
                .each(function(d) { this._current = d; }) // store the initial angles
                .transition()
                .delay(function(d, i) { return (i * 20) + 50; })
                .attr('fill', function(d) { return color(d.data.label); })
                .attr('d', arc);             

            arcs.exit().remove();

            $compile(svg[0])(scope);
          }
        }, true);
      }
    };
}]);
```

I'm noticing that after this runs for a minute or so, it gets incredibly slow and unresponsive.  If I profile while mousing over the elements, I see that it's spending an exorbitant amount of time in `$interpolate.fn`.  According to the profiler, the call stack is:

hideTooltipBind -> Scope.$apply -> Scope.$digest -> $interpolate.fn

(where hideTooltipBind is in ui-bootstrap-tpls.js)

I am guessing that on the repeat calls to $compile, the old tooltips are not cleaned up?  Is this a bug in angular-bootstrap or is the problem in my code?

Edit: It seems that on the repeat call to $compile, the child scope created by the first call to $compile is not destroyed, and $destroy is what unregisters the bindings for the tooltips.  Not sure how to destroy the old child context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by manually destroying all child scopes of the directive scope before calling $compile. Since this directive uses an isolated scope this should be safe. If anyone has a better idea I'd love to hear it.

Code:

```
var destroyer = function(scopeElem) {
  if(scopeElem.$$nextSibling) {
    destroyer(scopeElem.$$nextSibling);
  }
  scopeElem.$destroy();
};

if(scope.$$childHead) {
  destroyer(scope.$$childHead);
}

$compile(svg[0])(scope);
```